# Date was reflected in the code but it is not showing in database

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VXJq.png)I am trying to get the current time into the  database from my application. I tried and the an empty date string was pushed in the database instead.

Comment: please add more details with code as text not image?

Answer (score 0):

this is because firestore use is own [date format](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). Or you can try to use:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

But I suggest you to use the firestore Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

the `new Date()`constructor doesn't return a string in your case

you can do it this way  :

```js
mounted(){
 var date = new Date();
 database.once('value', pages =>{
  pages.forEach(page => {
    this.pages.push({
     ...
     datetime : date.toJSON();
    })
   }
 }
}
```